# Replacing .Click() Function in Jquery with some other name

Tags: jquery

I want to replace .click() function by some other name for example .xyz()
how do I write a function for it.

Comment: use the extend method, available in jQuery. Else you can call click() function in xyz() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try jQuery  $.extend method.

For Ex:

```
 $.extend($.fn, {
        xyz: function (method, data) {
//do whatever 
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends on your purpose; if you want to simply have a function called every time a `.click()` happens, you can use `$('#id').bind('click', function() { /* do something */ })`. Returning `false` at the end of the scope of the bound function, stops events from [propagating](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the detailed documentation here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

And do it this way,

```
$.extend($.fn, {
        yourFunctionName : function (method, data) {
            // your code
        }
});
```